# Combining two Option[List[String]] in Scala

Tags: scala

I have two Options

```
val opt1 = Some(List("Sal", "Salil"))
val opt2 = Some(List("Sal2", "Salil2"))
```

Either opt1 or opt2 could be None. If either one is None then I want an option with the List contained in the other. If both are None then None should be returned.

If both are Some then a Some with a list containing elements from both lists as shown below:

```
Some(List(Sal, Salil, Sal2, Salil2))
```

I know I can do this by hand, but is there an elegant way to do this? For-comprehensions don't work if one of the Options is a None.

Comment: google search is not in favor of stack overflow anymore? i had to put search like this "cats combine 2 options" to get this; other search which i did not put 'cats' did not lead me to here.

Answer (score 13):

```
Option((opt1 ++ opt2).flatten.toList).filter(_.nonEmpty)
```

Comment: This does not return the correct value if both inputs are `Some(List())`. This should return `Some(List())`, but your solution returns `None`.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this nicely using semigroup appending with scalaz or cats:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._ // for cats use `import cats._, implicits._`

val opt1 = Option(List("Sal", "Salil"))
val opt2 = Option(List("Sal2", "Salil2"))

scala> opt1 |+| opt2
res0: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(Sal, Salil, Sal2, Salil2))

scala> opt1 |+| None
res1: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(Sal, Salil))

scala> Option.empty[List[String]] |+| None
res2: Option[List[String]] = None
```

Otherwise, with the standard library you may need to handle it case-by-case:

```
(opt1, opt2) match {
    case (Some(a), Some(b)) => Option(a ++ b)
    case (Some(a), None) => Option(a)
    case (None, Some(b)) => Option(b)
    case _ => None
}
```

Or use collection methods to flatten them down:

```
scala> List(opt1, opt2).flatten.flatten
res5: List[String] = List(Sal, Salil, Sal2, Salil2)

scala> List(opt1, None).flatten.flatten
res6: List[String] = List(Sal, Salil)
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is only one, proper, elegant way to achieve that.
There is my proposition:

```
val opt1 = Some(List("Sal", "Salil"))
val opt2 = Some(List("Sal2", "Salil2"))

def merge(xs: Option[Iterable[_]]*) = xs.flatten.reduceLeftOption(_ ++ _)
```

With the results:

```
merge (opt1, opt2)
res1: Option[Iterable[_]] = Some(List(Sal, Salil, Sal2, Salil2))

merge (None, opt2)
res2: Option[Iterable[_]] = Some(List(Sal2, Salil2))

merge (opt1, None)
res5: Option[Iterable[_]] = Some(List(Sal, Salil))

merge (None, None)
res6: Option[Iterable[_]] = None
```

Answer (score 4):

No `flatten` required.

```
opt1.fold(opt2)(lst => Some(lst ++ opt2.getOrElse(Nil)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using for and yield:

```
  val xys = for {
    _  <- if(xs.isEmpty && ys.isEmpty) None else Some(List())
    x <-  if(xs.isDefined) xs else Some(List())
    y <- if(ys.isDefined) ys else Some(List())
  } yield List(x,y).flatten
```

Comment: Does not produce the requested result if either input is `None`.

Comment: Right you are jwvh, I updated the answer to handle None

Comment: Alas, now it doesn't produce the requested result if _both_ inputs are `None`.

Comment: @jwvh I'm a year late, but I updated the answer again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation combining the `++`/`flatten` approach with a `match` at the end.

```scala
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val opt1 = Some(List("Sal", "Salil"))
val opt2 = Some(List("Sal2", "Salil2"))
val opt3 = None

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

opt1: Some[List[String]] = Some(List(Sal, Salil))
opt2: Some[List[String]] = Some(List(Sal2, Salil2))
opt3: None.type = None

scala> (opt1.toList ++ opt2.toList).flatten match { case Nil => None; case x => Some(x) }
res0: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(Sal, Salil, Sal2, Salil2))

scala> (opt1.toList ++ opt3.toList).flatten match { case Nil => None; case x => Some(x) }
res1: Option[List[String]] = Some(List(Sal, Salil))

scala> (opt3.toList ++ opt3.toList).flatten match { case Nil => None; case x => Some(x) }
res2: Option[List[Nothing]] = None
```